# MVC app filter attribute in CSS 3 is causing app not to compile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, css

I have an MVC app. I was trying to get some gradients working for IE 8 so I added:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#E65C00', endColorstr='#FFB280');
```

This was working fine for a while. Now my app won't compile and is saying:

Validation (CSS 2.1): 'filter' is not a known CSS property name

This was not an issue before but now is. Strange.

I'm new to CSS 3 but I'm thinking the problem is probably Visual Studio is trying to compile to this CSS 2.1. Am I right? How would I set it up to validate for CSS 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'filter' property is a proprietary Microsoft CSS extension. This is not the part of CSS 2.1 specification. [See this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/filter).

You can turn off CSS validation errors in Visual Studio from menu: - Tools > Options. See the following image. In this way you can successfully compile your project.

[image]